# Is there a way to use ctrl-d as forward delete in Scala's REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

So in the Scala REPL, I can use the ctrl-{p,n,a,e} to do previous-, next-, beginning of- and end of line. However, I'll soon go crazy if I can't use ctrl-d to forward-delete.

Is it possible to achieve this in some way?

I'm using a Mac.

**Update**

Add the following lines to the accepted answer to get ctrl-{a,e}. A larger keybindings file kan be found in the jline2 repo [jline2 repo at GitHub](https://github.com/jdillon/jline2/blob/master/src/main/resources/jline/keybindings.properties).

```
# CTRL-A: move to the beginning of the line
1=MOVE_TO_BEG

# CTRL-E: move the cursor to the end of the line
5=MOVE_TO_END
```

**Update2**

I just installed Scala 2.9.0.final and I can confirm that the ctrl-d is now working as it should. It's forward delete unless it's an empty line when it terminates the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very minimal keybinding property file, including your desired `^D`:

```
# CTRL-B: move to the previous character
2: PREV_CHAR

# CTRL-D: delete the previous character
4: DELETE_NEXT_CHAR

# CTRL-F: move to the next character
6: NEXT_CHAR

# BACKSPACE, CTRL-H: delete the previous character
# 8 is the ASCII code for backspace and therefor
# deleting the previous character
8: DELETE_PREV_CHAR

# TAB, CTRL-I: signal that console completion should be attempted
9: COMPLETE

# CTRL-J, CTRL-M: newline
10: NEWLINE

# ENTER: newline
13: NEWLINE

# CTRL-N: scroll to the next element in the history buffer
14: NEXT_HISTORY

# CTRL-P: scroll to the previous element in the history buffer
16: PREV_HISTORY

# CTRL-V: paste the contents of the clipboard (useful for Windows terminal)
22: PASTE

# DELETE, CTRL-?: delete the previous character
# 127 is the ASCII code for delete
127: DELETE_PREV_CHAR
```

Put it in a file, and call scala like this:

```
scala -Djline.keybindings=/path/to/keybindings.properties
```

Or pass it through `JAVA_OPTS`. You'll have to look up on the Internet what keybindings exist, and try `:keybindings` from Scala to see what are the defaults (it won't reflect your actual keybindings, though).

Answer (score 3):

in scala 2.9's REPL you have a new :keybindings command. This reveals:

```
scala> :keybindings
Reading jline properties for default key bindings.
Accuracy not guaranteed: treat this as a guideline only.

  1 CTRL-A: move to the beginning of the line
  2 CTRL-B: move to the previous character
  4 CTRL-D: close out the input stream
  5 CTRL-E: move the cursor to the end of the line
  6 CTRL-F: move to the next character
  7 CTRL-G: abort
  8 BACKSPACE, CTRL-H: delete the previous character 8 is the ASCII code for backspace and therefor deleting the previous character
  9 TAB, CTRL-I: signal that console completion should be attempted
 10 CTRL-J, CTRL-M: newline
 11 CTRL-K: erase the current line
 12 CTRL-L: clear screen
 13 ENTER: newline
 14 CTRL-N: scroll to the next element in the history buffer
 15 CTRL-O: move to the previous word
 16 CTRL-P: scroll to the previous element in the history buffer
 18 CTRL-R: redraw the current line
 21 CTRL-U: delete all the characters before the cursor position
 22 CTRL-V: paste the contents of the clipboard (useful for Windows terminal)
 23 CTRL-W: delete the word directly before the cursor
127 DELETE, CTRL-?: delete the next character 127 is the ASCII code for delete
```

on the macbook laptops, `DELETE` can be accessed via `Fn + BACKSPACE`.